# Creating an alternating tile floor with a nested loop

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a program that outputs an alternate tile design from the user's input. I.E. if  the use inputs 3 the result would be a 3x3 design that looks like:

```
|R|B|R|
|B|R|B| 
|R|B|R|
```

I'm having problems with getting the right amount of tiles for the output. For the input of 3, row 2 has an extra "|R|" and a 4th row is subsequently created. The output comes out to:

```
|R|B|R|
|B|R|B|R|
|R|B|R|
|B
```

I've attached my code below. I know it has something to do with:

```
if (r%2 == 0){
System.out.println("|");
System.out.print("|B");
```

Any thoughts?

```
import java.util.*;

public class tileFloor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter x:");
        int x;
            x = input.nextInt();

    if (x < 10)
    { int c = 0;
      int r = 0;

      while (r < x ){
          while (c < x ){
              if (c %2 == 0 )
                System.out.print("|R");
              else if (c%2 != 0)
                System.out.print("|B");

            c++;

          }//end 'while (c<x)' loop

        if (r%2 == 0){
            System.out.println("|");
            System.out.print("|B");
        }
        else if (r%2 != 0)
            System.out.println("|");

        c = 0;
        r++;

       }//end 'while (r<x)' loop

    }//end if statement

    input.close();

}//end main

}//end class
```

Comment: Why don't you use a for-loop instead of a while? Since you know the amount of times it should iterate?

Comment: It sounds like a great idea, but I'm not comfortable with them

Comment: You should get comfortable with them. While loops are dangerous because a simple mistake can mean they never exit. Far FAR less likely to happen with for loops.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind the next time I'm working with loops. Thanks for the concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    import java.util.*;

class tileFloor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter x:");
        int x;
            x = input.nextInt();
   int count = 0;
    if (x < 10)
    { int c = 0;
      int r = 0;

      while (r < x ){
        if(r%2 == 0)
        {
            count = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            count = 1;
        }
          while (c < x ){


              if (count %2 == 0)
                {
                    System.out.print("|R");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print("|B");
                }

            count++;
            c++;

          }//end 'while (c<x)' loop


            System.out.println("|");

        c = 0;
        r++;

       }//end 'while (r<x)' loop

    }//end if statement

    input.close();

}//end main

}//end class
```

Comment: This works fine with odd number inputs, but doesn't alternate with even inputs

Answer (score 1):

What about this solution? It's definitly more clear what it does:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        System.out.print("Enter x: ");
        int x = input.nextInt();

        if (x < 10) {
            int r = x;
            int c;

            while (r-- > 0) {
                c = x;

                while (c-- > 0) {
                    System.out.print("|" + ((c + r & 1) == 0 ? "R" : "B"));
                }

                System.out.println("|");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, OP didn't really mention what he was expecting as a result... But now I'm guessing it's something like a chess field...  I corrected my answer!

Comment: Definitely cleaner, but as mentioned above, I have trouble with for loops. Thanks for your response, though!